# Wenn Leute sagen, dass das deutsche Wort "Mist" "Gülle" bedeutet, ist das wahr oder nur ein Witz?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

Ich habe im Internet einen Beitrag gelesen, dass das Wort ***Mist*** so viel bedeutet wie:

> - Gülle
> - Fäkalien
> - Abwasser
> - Skat
> - Tierkot

Vor vielen Jahren schrieb jemand im Internet über ein Tal voller Wolken. Alternativ war es ein mit Wassertropfen gefülltes Tal.

In der englischen Sprache ist "***mist***" eine Ansammlung von Wassertröpfchen, so dass jedes Tröpfchen kleiner als ein Staubkorn ist.

War das ein Scherz oder ist das echt? Ich freue mich, wenn das deutsche Wort für "***mist***" "Gülle" bedeutet, aber ich möchte anderen Leuten nicht sagen, dass ***mist*** im Deutschen ein Synonym für Gülle ist, es sei denn, mehr als 5% der Menschen in Deutschland nach dem Jahr 2000 verwenden das Wort ***mist*** tatsächlich so.

Comment: Since I can't PM you directly on this platform? Do you write your questions in German, yourself, or do you use some form of automated translation?

Comment: In your question you refer both to the German "Mist" and the English "mist", but it is not always clear which you mean. I suggest that you edit your question to make it precise by using a capital "M" for the German word. It seems to me the English "mist" onyl occurs once in the sentence "n der englischen Sprache ist "**mist**" ... "

Comment: Das dt. Wort für `mist` ist Dunst, Nebel usw. und eben nicht `Mist`. Das dt. Wort Mist bedeutet dagegen Gülle, Dung usw.

Comment: Das deutsche Wort "Skat" ist kein Synonym zum Englischen "scat", sondern ein Kartenspiel, und gehört dazer nicht in die Auflistung oben.

Comment: A perfume with the original name "irish mist" had to be renamed for the German market because of the meaning of the German word "Mist" (= *dung* or *crap*). They invented "Irisch Moos" = "irish moss".

Comment: @Arsak Ja, aber: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Skatologie

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Das deutsche Wort "Mist" bezieht sich tatsächlich auf tierische Ausscheidungen. "Gülle" stimmt nicht ganz, wie Janka schon erklärt hat; als englische Entsprechung könnte man "dung" oder "manure" sehen.

Entsprechend ist der deutsche "Misthaufen" der englische "dung heap". Und der Ausdruck, dass jemand "Mist baut", bedeutet ungefähr "to blunder", "to mess something up".

Das englische Wort "mist" wiederum könnte man im Deutschen als "Nebel", "Sprühnebel" oder "Dunst" ausdrücken.

Das Paar "mist" und "Mist" ist also ein sogenannter "falscher Freund": Eine scheinbare Entsprechung, bei der die beiden Begriffe aber unterschiedliche Dinge bedeuteten. Andere Beispiele sind "to become" - "bekommen", "brave" - "brav", "eventually" - "eventuell" oder "fabric" - "Fabrik".

Answer (score 6):

*Mist* ist nicht dasselbe wie *Gülle*. Gülle bezeichnet ein flüssiges Gemisch aus Kot und Urin. Mist ist hingegen weitestgehend trocken, weil an Einstreu, meist Stroh gebunden.

Comment: Nach Ihrer Beschreibung lautet das englische Wort für Gülle "***sewage***"

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon [Sewage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sewage) ist allgemeiner und meint Wasser, das von einer Gemeinschaft (z. B. einer Stadt) gebraucht und verschmutzt wurde. Die deutsche Entsprechung dafür wäre "Abwasser" oder "Schmutzwasser".  [Gülle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%BClle) wiederum entspricht eher [liquid manure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_manure).